# Is it possible to send a mail body with jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, email

i wonder if i could send the mail to recipient with a jquery plugin in mail body, using php.

for example: i am using the jquery flip plugin, and if i include the code in mail body, will it work or able to see in receiver's end.

how to do this?

```
function purchaseOrder($user_email,$product_name,$price)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
            if (defined(EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION)) {
                $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
            }
            $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
            $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
            $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        } else {
            $mail->IsMail();
        }
        $mail->From = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_FROM;
        $mail->FromName = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_FROM_NAME;
        $mail->AddAddress($user_email);
        $mail->Subject = PURCHASE_ORDER_SUBJECT;
        //$link = INVITE_LINK;
        $mail->Body = //here check if working jquery plugin can be sent? so that receiver will be able to see it
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_NOT_SENT . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;            
        } else {        
            return true;            
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok..and what about `jQuery` itself? are you going to send it as well?

Comment: @vijayP jquery.js file may be from cdn, but i want to send only the plugin.

Comment: then why can't to refer plugin from cdn or your own web server?

Comment: @vijayP will it open in reciepent's browser?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I am fairly sure that you cannot execute js/jQuery in a mail as it would be a security issue.

Comment: MithunRaikar - yes; well known CDN are always trusted. But also keep in mind what @Epodax suggested. It will give a security warning popup, and it will run only if user allowed it to proceed.